# Reference Multiple Models in One MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Ia m trying to learn MVC and have been following the Getting Started with Entity Framework 6 Code First using MVC 5 (https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) but change it to be a little drinks generator program (basically taking parts out and using my own idea to try and learn).

I have created a personController, Person (Index, Create, Delete, Details & Edit) Views and a person class which is listed below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;


namespace DOSTeaDecider.Models
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        //public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Biography")]
        public string bio { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Drink Choice")]
        public string Drink { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Sugar Amount")]
        public int Sugar { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Milk Colour")]
        public string MilkColour { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Milk Dosage")]
        public string MilkDose { get; set; }       

    }
}
```

In my view I would like to display the people based off the properties set in the model so I have something like the following which works great; however in the tutorial I am following they are using PagedList e.g. `@model PagedList.IPagedList<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>` in the view and then they are able to call the properties of `PagedList.IPagedList` from the view. The problem I have is if I include two `@model` declarations in the view it doesn't like it but if I remove the reference to the person model I can't use the person properties, e.g. `model.LastName` and if I remove the reference to the PagedList.IPagedList I am unable to call the properties from this, e.g., `Model.PageCount`:

```
@model IEnumerable<DOSTeaDecider.Models.Person>
@*@model PagedList.IPagedList<DOSTeaDecider.Models.Person>*@
@*@using PagedList.Mvc;*@
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Person", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
}
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("First Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)*@
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Drink)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Sugar)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MilkColour)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MilkDose)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Drink)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sugar)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MilkColour)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MilkDose)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
<br />
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
    new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

I have tried to research and creating references in the person model to the PagedList but so far my efforts have failed. I think I may be missing something simple, but I am learning and that's why I have asked on here so that maybe someone could please advise.

Comment: You should use viewmodel here to collect data in one place.

Comment: You can't have two models in one view. You must create a ViewModel class to hold one Person property and one PagedList<Person> property. Like so: `public Person Person {get; set;}` and `public PagedList<Person> People { get; set; }`

Comment: Thansk for the response both. I have tried using a view model but still having issues. Created a viewmodel called PersonViewModel and populated it with what you suggested. I then put the following '@model reference in the @model IEnumerable<DOSTeaDecider.Models.ViewModels.PersonViewModel>' View but still no luck

Answer (score 1):

Using PagedList as a view model, try to display properties of the entity using some explicitly defined object:

```
var sampleObject = Model.First();
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => sampleObject.FirstName)
```

or

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => new Person().FirstName)
```

In this case you can use the PagedList in a standard way.

Comment: Is it good practice to create an instance of the person class at the top of the view like so `@{ ViewBag.Title = "Index";   Person person = new Person();}` and then do the following to list the properties in the table `<th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => person.LastName)
        </th>`

Comment: Yes, of course, if you want to use the entity many times it will be a good solution to define it on the top.

Comment: If it is a solution for your problem, please mark the post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the display name from the first row:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Person[0].FirstName)
```